The diameter of the projection of a convex core
Let $M$ be a closed hyperbolic 3-manifold and $H_{g}$ a genus g handlebody. Assume that $\pi: int(H_{g})\rightarrow M$ is a cover. Denote $N\subset H_{g}$ the convex core.
My question is:  If the diameter of $\pi(\partial N)$ is finite in $M$,  is the diameter of $\pi(N) $ bounded by the diameter of $\pi(\partial N)$?
Thank you!

It can’t be a regular cover. Any finitely generated non-trivial normal subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$ is a closed surface group or a 3-manifold group.

Also, since $M$ is closed, all diameters in $M$ are finite.

So presumably you want to delete the “regular” hypothesis too?

Sorry, I should delete the regular hypothesis.

No, this won’t hold in general. One may construct manifolds with $\pi(N)$ of unbounded diameter and $\pi(\partial N)$ bounded diameter. I might try to write a more complete answer, but to summarize: one may take a hyperbolic handlebody with convex core $N$ and $\partial N$ of bounded diameter but $N$ of  arbitrarily large diameter. Perturb a bit so that one may extend by a reflection group using Thurston’s reflection trick, then a manifold cover will have $N$ embedded and hence won’t satisfy your conditions.

Thank you, Ian.   If I understand your example correctly,   $\partial N$ is compressible from both sides.  May I ask that: will the diameter of $N$ be bounded by the diameter of $\partial N$  if  $\partial N$  is separating and incompressible from one side?

@yanqing: No, this construction will be compressible only from one side.

Take a Schottky group $\Gamma$ with convex core $N\subset \mathbb{H}^3/\Gamma$ with $diam(N)$ large, but $diam(\partial N)$ bounded. Then by a theorem of Robert Brooks, there is a small deformation $\Gamma_\epsilon$ of $\Gamma$ so that $\Gamma_\epsilon$ has a cocompact extension. The construction is by extension by a reflection group such that the convex core $N_\epsilon$ embeds in the quotient. Then the diameter of the projection will be arbitrarily large but the boundary remains bounded.
The existence of such $\Gamma$ follows from the theory of Kleinian groups.
For example, one may take a handlebody $H$ and a mapping class $f:\partial H\to \partial H$ which is sufficiently “generic” (its stable lamination has positive intersection number with any lamination in the Masur domain of $H$), then modifying the conformal structure on the boundary of a Schottky group hyperbolic metric on $H$ by $f^n$ gives a sequence of hyperbolic manifolds which converge to the infinite-cyclic cover of the mapping torus on one end, and hence the approximates have diameter of the convex core approacing infinity but bounded geometry. This can be deduced from the proof in this paper.

Thank you, Ian, especially for giving a clear construction.
